# RaspberryPi cpu temperatures spikes

Tags: raspberry-pi

I've got my Rasp with the latest firmware update and I´m doing SoC temperature reads every 5minutes (300seconds). I came across several temperature spikes ( from 50º to 70º and sometimes to down to 30ºC). These temperature spikes happen 2-3 sometimes 4 times everyday. 
I've read there are some readout glitches on the temperature sensor, yet can this be a hardware malfunction? Maybey a software update (linux) will solve the problem?

I'm currently using it as a small homeserver, but if temperature spikes persist I'd probably have to get a passive cooler.

I'm also sure that during those upper spikes the workload of cpu/IO/gpu is kept the same.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Spiking & coming back down so fast I would say its the sensor...

Comment: I'd say the same, yet after my posted "solution" I did not happen again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It´s not exactly a solution but it solved my problem. I changed the SD card (8gb generic class 4) to a micro-sd adapter+sandisk 16gb class 10, installed the same raspbian (in fact the same image file!), also did the system updates and after 24hours running didn't noticed any spikes. 
Maybee an SD card write/problem? 
The sd card wasn't full by the way.